# Constructing a triangle given two angles and the sum of two sides

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I am looking for an answer to the following construction

> Construct a triangle given two angles (3 angles) and the sum of two sides

Comment: There are (except for some special angles) three such triangles. They can all be constructed fairly easily by straightedge and compass. Just construct a triangle with correct angles, and scale.

Comment: Only the sum of two sides is given !

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:  Draw a line $AB$ of arbitrary length. Copy angle $\alpha$ at point $A$ and angle $\beta$ at point $B$ to  form $\triangle ABC$.

Step 2: Extend line $AB$ in the direction of $B$ by length $AC$, calling that line $AD$.

Step 3: Draw line a perpendicular to $AD$ at $A$, and mark off the given required sum of two sides $s$ such that the length of $AE$ is $s$.  Connect points $D$ and $E$ to form line $DE$.

Step 4: construct a line parallel to $DE$ passing through point $B$.  This line intersects line $AE$ at some point $F$.

Step 5: Copy angle $\alpha$ such that one leg is on $AF$ and the vertex is at $A$.  Copy angle $\alpha$ such that one leg is on $AF$ and the vertex is at $A$.  Copy angle $\beta$ such that one leg is on $AF$ and the vertex is at $F$.  The two new lines meet at some point $G$.

Triangle $AFG$ is the required triangle.

Note that the solution is not unique, unless the problem has specified that the sum of two sides meeting at a specific one of the angles must be the given sum.

Comment: I am sorry but this answer doesn't work. It seems that AF is omger than AE which is the orignal a+b.

Comment: I am going to rephrase my question . I have a triangle with the three angles , and one side is a+b .

Comment: I need to find a SIMILAR triangle with sides a and b

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let us suppose the problem is solved and $\triangle ABC$ is our desired triangle. Extend $AB$ from $B$ to point $H$ such that $|BH| = |BC|$ and so $|AH|=|AB|+|BC|$. Note that $\widehat H = \frac12 \widehat{ABC}$ (why?)

Now let us suppose the problem is not solved. We only have the three angles of $\triangle ABC$ and the sum of lengths $|AB|+|BC|$. We can construct $\triangle AHC$ (why?) and you can surely do the rest.